# Java Variable Length Arguments to Scala

Tags: java, scala, variadic-functions

I am implementing an extension of an abstract class from that library which has this signature:

```
Object filter(Object var, JinjavaInterpreter interpreter, String... args);
```

Which I think I should implement as the following in Scala

```
def filter(obj: Any, jinjavaInterpreter: JinjavaInterpreter, args: String*): Any = {
...
}
```

However, when I try to access items from args (eg `args(0)`, I get type coercion errors:
`Cannot coerce '0' of class java.lang.String to class [Ljava.lang.String;`

Comment: Please provide a runnable example that demonstrates this error - you're more likely to get help and useful help.

Comment: Who gives you the "coercion errors"?

Comment: Implementing `T... xs` of a Java class as `xs: T*` in Scala works for me (Scala 2.11.8). Seems your problem lies elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

It seems the coercion errors means that class String can't be cast to String[]:

> Cannot coerce '0' of class java.lang.String to class [Ljava.lang.String;

I bet args(0) is of class String which is correct.

Your signature is correct and I also bet that the error is other else.